# How to print a label layer in the ArcGIS Server JS API

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, labeling, printing

I'm trying to use a [PrintTask](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/printtask-amd.html) to print a map, but am finding that a [LabelLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/labellayer-amd.html) does not correctly print.

I modified the [Label Layer sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_label.html) to include a Print Task, and found that the label layer is simply ignored - only the basemap and polygon layer are included on the printout. See [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slead/tof4asgz/) to reproduce.

Is a label layer supported in the print task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug introduced at version 3.14. It seems to work fine with 3.11-3.13.

Comment: FYI: I've already logged it as a bug.